# Azure function application settings to pick enviroment other than production, staging and development

Tags: azure-functions

Azure function app provides app setting tab in azure portal.where I can created key as Azure_Functions_Environment and values as production, staging or development and it would be picked at runtime accordingly. But when I set value as UAT or Sandbox. at runtime system will still pick value as 'development'. Does anybody know reason behind it.

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.x and later versions of the Functions runtime, configures app behavior based on the runtime environment. **This value is read during initialization.** You can set `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` to any value, but three values are supported: `Development`, `Staging`, and `Production`. When `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` isn't set, **it defaults to Development on a local environment and Production on Azure.** This setting should be used instead of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to set the runtime environment.

For more details you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azure_functions_environment).

Comment: If it helps you, please accept it as answer. Click the ckeckmark beside my reply to turn to green. Thanks.